# Monte Carlo Pi not accurate

Tags: c#, montecarlo

I am having trouble with my Monte Carlo Pi program calculating properly.
Basically, pi is only displaying up to 2 decimal points only at the moment, and I feel the calculation has gone wrong somewhere as the closest pi calculation as number gets higher is 2.98-3.04.

My code is pasted below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double n;
    double count;
    double c = 0.0;
    double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
    double pi;
    string input;

    Console.WriteLine("Please input a number of dots for Monte Carlo to calculate pi.");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    n = double.Parse(input);

    Random rand = new Random();


    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        x = rand.Next(-1, 1);
        y = rand.Next(-1, 1);

        if (((x * x) + (y * y) <= 1))
            c++;
        pi = 4.0 * ( c / i );
        Console.WriteLine("pi: {0,-10:0.00} Dots in square: {1,-15:0} Dots in circle: {2,-20:0}", pi, i, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What n do you enter?

Comment: @Sam greetings. So would you recommend for me to re-write the post?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've entered "n" in all kinds of numbers varying from 50 to 100,000 and the answer never seems to get closer to actual pi as it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calls

```
x = rand.Next(-1, 1);
y = rand.Next(-1, 1);
```

give you an integer. But you need `doubles`:

```
x = rand.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
y = rand.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
```

Comment: thankyou it works now, didn't realise that was the case :) thanks a lot I will select the answer when it has been 5minutes

Answer (score 0):

The random numbers should be generated between 0 and 1 and not -1 and 1.
Used this fixed version of your code as "mysterious code" for students.

```
using System;

namespace mysCode
{
    class Program
    {
        static double euclideanDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
        {
            double dX = x2 - x1;
            double dY = y2 - y1;
            return Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double n;            
            double c = 0.0;
            double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
            double result;
            string input;
            Console.WriteLine("Quick, pick an integer");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            n = double.Parse(input);
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                x = rand.NextDouble();
                y = rand.NextDouble();
                if (euclideanDistance(x, y, 0, 0) <= 1)
                    c++;
                result = 4.0 * (c / i);                
                Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

It coverages very slowly, I get 3.14152314152314 after 1M iterations.